# Passagem múltipla para parâmetro simples no Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, funções

Criei uma função no Postgresql onde faço a soma de determinadas contas. Porém, minha função tem somente um parâmetro para elas:

```
f_retorna_somatorio(p_conta character varying, p_cnpj character varying, p_ano_mes character varying)
```

O parâmetro "p_conta", precisa receber três valores: 300001, 300002, 300003

Vou utilizar isso dentro de um IN. Sempre que faço select na função ele está me retornando 0 por causa de um coalesce.

Alguém sabe como fazer essa passagem?

Obs: Testei o seguinte exemplo já e não funcionou:

```
f_retorna_somatorio($$'300001','300002','300003'$$, '00000000000000', '0000-00')
```

Comment: Tentou chamar com '300001,300002,300003'?

Comment: Outra possibilidade é, dentro de sua função, montar a string de sua query e executá-la utilizando o EXECUTE. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Altere a sua function para receber um array de string no parâmetro `p_conta` declarando-o como `p_conta character varying[]`. Dessa forma você pode informar vários valores em uma só variável.

No comando SQL na consulta dentro da função ao invés de utilizar o `IN` utilize `ANY`, recebendo o array `p_conta`. Você não postou o código da função mas seria semelhante ao exemplo a seguir:

```
select *
from tabela
where campo = any(p_conta);
```

E para executar a função basta informar o array semelhante o exemplo a seguir:

```
select f_retorna_somatorio(array['300001','300002','300003'], '00000000000000', '0000-00');
```

Comment: gracias amigo :)

Comment: Funciona também para caso de parâmetros numéricos?

Comment: Funciona sim. É só você definir o parâmetro com o tipo `integer[]` por exemplo e informar os valores no select com o construtor do array: `array[123,456,789]`